# Cannot resolve Input shape inconsistencies for input to LSTM network

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

The goal of my project is to predict taylor series expansions of functions using LSTM's upto the 4th power. I have tokenized and padded these functions along with their taylor expansions. So this can basically be thought of a multi-label classification problem where the goal is to predict each token value of the taylor expansion of the given function.

As an example, sin(x) = -x**3/6 + x (Original) tokenized into:-
['5' '3' '4' '0' '6' '1' '2' '2' '2' '2' '2'] (function) ;
[2, 7, 0, 0, 5, 3, 6, 1, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,4, 4, 4, 4, 4] (expansion)

Shape of padded and tokenized input is : (19,11) (19 functions with padded size 11)
Shape of expected output (19,41) (padded output size 41)

Having said this, here is the model I used:-

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 11,return_sequences = True,input_shape = (19,11)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Model: "sequential_14"

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_12 (LSTM)              (None, 19, 11)            1012      
                                                                 
 dropout_18 (Dropout)        (None, 19, 11)            0         
                                                                 
 dense_12 (Dense)            (None, 19, 41)            492       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,504
Trainable params: 1,504
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

**However,upon fitting,I get the following error:-**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-e066679db599> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=32)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_14" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 19, 11), found shape=(None, 11)
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue? TIA

I tried changing the shapes of X taken as input but it didnt work